# Flutter Dart Firebase error: The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, dart-null-safety

I want to check if the user is currently registered, but I get a problem with the not null errors. Please have a look at my code:

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; void getCurrentUser() async {
final user = await _auth!.currentUser();}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're calling it as a `Function`, but you can get the current user information directly with `currentUser`, not `currentUser()`:

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
_auth.currentUser(); // wrong way
_auth.currentUser; // right way
```

`currentUser()` doesn't exist, `currentUser` does.